# JQuery selector in event handler

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have this markup with a div and three child divs:

```
<div class='all'>
   <div class='x'>Hello from x div</div>
   <div class='y'>Hello from y div</div>
   <div class='z'>Hello from z div</div>
</div>
```

With my event handler I take care of when the user clicks somewhere in the div with class x.

```
$('.all').on('click', '.x', function (e) {
   alert('You clicked inside the x div')
});
```

Now comes my question. Can I write an event handler that responds to everything *not* coming from a click on the class x? Something like:

```
$('.all') * .not. * on('click', '.x', function (e) {
   alert('You clicked inside something different from the x div')
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use the jQuery [:not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector

```
$('.all').on('click', ':not(.x)', function (e) {
   alert('You clicked inside something different from the x div')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector.

```
$('.all').on('click', ':not(.x)', function (e) {
   alert('You clicked inside something different from the x div')
});
```

```js
$('.all').on('click', ':not(.x)', function (e) {
   alert('You clicked inside something different from the x div')
});
```

```html
<div class='all'>
   <div class='x'>Hello from x div</div>
   <div class='y'>Hello from y div</div>
   <div class='z'>Hello from z div</div>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```